# Getting an element from a list in Tcl at a particular index for a given condition

Tags: tcl

Consider that I have two lists in a Tcl code :

```
a : { 1 2 3 4 5}
b : {p q r s t}
```

Now, I need to check the indices of the elements from list a which are more than 3, and print the elements from list b at those same indices. For example, in list a, the element at index 3 is 4, so my code should return me the element at index 3 of the list b, i.e., 4. Let us assume that a and b always have equal number of elements.

I can use the lindex command to access each element if a contains few elements and then use an if-else ladder to get the desired outputs for all the cases, but for large number of elements in a, this method wouldn't be suitable. How can I do it?

Comment: Is there a problem with just looping over all elements of a?  That's what the `foreach` is for.  https://wiki.tcl.tk/1018

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use a double-list `foreach`:

```
set results {}
foreach a_elem $a b_elem $b {
    if {$a_elem > 3} {
        lappend results $b_elem
    }
}

# Result is now in $results
```

You can use `lmap` in 8.6 to do this more succinctly:

```
set results [lmap a_elem $a b_elem $b {
    if {$a_elem > 3} {string cat $b_elem} else continue
}]
```

The `continue` is important with `lmap`, as it skips the value from that iteration.